# Best place to query for components' size

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Within the constructor of `Page`, I try to query its components size.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Get the canvas size.
        double height = canvas.ActualHeight;
        double width = canvas.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

All I get in 0 height and width. May I know what is the best place to query for components' size?

Comment: ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be available when UI is displayed once on screen. Where you want to use these height and width?

Comment: Ya. So, which Page's method will be triggered, once the UI is displayed on screen? So that, I can override the method, and perform size query within it.

Comment: there is no such event. you need to make it tricky. can you fire some trigger from GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the canvas size.
        double height = canvas.ActualHeight;
        double width = canvas.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnNavigatedTo` get's triggered every time you navigate to a page. So might want to do it in there.

Comment: add `Loaded` event to your `Canvas` and do it there. That'll be the best place as the event will fire when the element is constructed and added to object tree.